# Volcano II Bluetooth Metal Speaker initiating calls

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, voice-dictation, speakers

I'm using a Volcano II Bluetooth Speaker with my iPhone. Since it once got connected to a friend iPhone, I noticed that my phone was randomly initiating calls to that friend, when I'm using the Speaker.
What is this caused by ? How to fix that ?
Please note Siri is disabled.

Comment: Please state your iOS version. Some versions had that Phantom calls issue.

Comment: @user9125: 10.1.1

Comment: I'd like to suggest you to reset your network settings. Assuming you have already tried restarting your phone. Apple Support suggested to reset that iPhone **Network Settings**. That would solve your problem.

Comment: @User9125 OK thanks for your input, I'm trying that.

Comment: If that worked please tell me. That would helpful for another person. Thank you.

Comment: @User9125 Sure, will post a reply here.

Comment: @User9125 that didnt work...

Comment: I haven't use that product. But when I read the manual it says this can use for handsfree calls. But I assume it cannot use to "make" calls. Since it doesn't have that feature according to my knowledge it is not possible that speaker will cause iPhone to make calls. Could you tell me whether there is a feature of reset that Bluetooth speaker settings? If it has that would be your best solution before digging up this problem more.